# Thread issue updating state of second level component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following structure for a part of my app, I'm trying to resemble a board game. A tile is an object { color1, color2, key }, and a HexTile is the React component that shows the tile.

```
class HexTile extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { color1, color2, key } = props.tile;
    let tile = [color1, color2];

    // Initialize hexagons with some color
    const hexagons = GridGenerator.orientedRectangle(2, 1).map((hexagon, index) => {
      return Object.assign({}, hexagon, {
        color: tile[index],
        tile: key
      });
    });

    this.state = { 
      hexagons,
      ...
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    ...,
    tile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    ...
  };

  render() {
    const { hexagons } = this.state;
    return (
      <Layout className="tile" size={{ x: 3, y: 3 }} flat={false} spacing={1.01} 
              origin={{ x: this.props.x, y: this.props.y }}>
        {
          hexagons.map((hex, i) => (
            <Hexagon
              key={i}
              ...
              data={hex}
            >
            </Hexagon>
          ))
        }
      </Layout>
    );
  }
```

TileList is a component that receives a list of tiles as props, saves it in its state and renders each tile:

```
class TileList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);

    const { tiles } = props;
    this.state = { 
      ...,
      tiles: tiles              
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { tiles } = this.state;
    return (
      <g>
        {
          tiles.map((tile, i) => (
            <HexTile key={i} 
                     ...
                     tile={tile}
                     onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}
                     ...
            />
          ))
        }
      </g>
    );
  }
```

The app is the main component, it saves the list of tiles in its state and renders the TileList, also it updates when a tile has been used and changes it for a new Tile.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // Event where the tile list is updated, this is working
    this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this);
    ...
    const playerTiles = App.generateTiles(6);

    this.state = { 
      ...
      playerTiles,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { playerTiles, ... } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <HexGrid width={1200} height={800} viewBox="-50 -30 50 100">
          ...
          <TileList className={'tiles'} 
                    tiles={playerTiles} 
                    onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd} 
                    ...
          />
        </HexGrid>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The state update between App and TileList is working, but the tile on the HexTile that should be updated is the same of the beginning and I don't know how to make it update. I don't include the event that generates the update because it includes another functionality, but I will add it if it's required. Nonetheless, I think the problem is in the initialization of HexTiles, but I haven't figure it out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the hexagons with your new prop data. Try updating your state in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(prevProps, nextProps){
    const { color1, color2, key } = nextProps.tile;
    const tile = [color1, color2];
    // Initialize hexagons with some color
    const hexagons = GridGenerator.orientedRectangle(2, 1).map((hexagon, index) => {
      return Object.assign({}, hexagon, {
        color: tile[index],
        tile: key
      });
    });

    this.state = { 
      hexagons,
      ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this method on both `TileList` and `HexTile`, the `TileList` wasn't updating its state correctly. Just to mention, the `componentWillReceiveProps` only needs the `nextProps` argument.